# Google Plus Share URL is in German?

Tags: google-plus

I am using the Google + share url, e.g. :

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.domain.com" target="_blank" ></a>
```

but the page I am directed to in the browser is always in German - why is this?

I realise that Chrome translates the page but my audience will only be English speakers so I was wondering if anyone had any ideas.

**EDIT**

Just thinking that it might be relevant to know that the url is a facebook fan page tab so I'm not sure if Facebook comes into this aswell and that's why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code off my own site and it was fine. The only thing I changed was I url encoded the link you are trying to share. Try opening the link directly in your browser to see if it solves the problem.

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com
```

The I don't know why it would redirect you to the German site, but let me know if this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am prety shure that the language of the site is determined by your ip. I am sitting in germany and also get the page rendered in german.  I changed the language of my browser to en-usa but it stays german.

EDIT

use the parmeter hl

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com&hl=en
```

https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#available-languages

Comment: hmm interesting, I am in Scotland

Comment: Its realy not the IP - I checked with an american IP and I still get a german page.